# AWS Cloudformation package wont update code

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-cli

I have this issue:
I have deployed a function with CF that is build with the aws cloudformation package command. The first deployment works perfect. But when it try to update the code nothing happens. This is what I do:

- Save changes to my local code and and CF and run aws cloudformation package (aws cloudformation package --template-file mycf.yml --s3-bucket mybucket --output-template-file packaged-mycf.yml --profile myprofile)
- I see in the packaged file that where is a new path under CodeUri (CodeUri: s3://mybucket/319bd03cb3cc8d50ceb80e52bf51c53c)
- I deploy the update (I do it in the console) I see under update that where is updates to the function
- The CF events says update to function is complete
- I go to code, the same old code nothing has changed

Have anyone else experienced the same?
I have tried to rename the CF file, script file and the packaged CF file. But it still get the same result.
Does anyone here have an ide on what i may try?

This is how the unpackaged function part of the CF looks like:

```
  CRFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      Description: Convert IAM Policy into SCP
      Handler: scpfunction.lambda_handler
      Runtime: python3.9
      Timeout: 30
      MemorySize: 128
      FunctionName: !Sub SCP-Function-${SCPName}
      CodeUri: src/
      Environment:
        Variables:
          SCPName: !Ref SCPName
          Policy: !Ref IAMPolicyToConvertToSCP
          OUs: !Ref OUs
          Description: !Ref Description
      Policies:
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Action:
              - organizations:CreatePolicy
              - organizations:AttachPolicy
              - organizations:List*
              - iam:get*
            Resource: '*'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this solved.
It was not an issue related to AWS.
After restarting VisualStudioCode I got the deployment to work. So it had to do with some local caching or something.
Really weird never experienced anything like that before.

Answer (score 2):

> Have anyone else experienced the same?

That's how it works by design. Changes to the source code are not detected. You have to change either [Key](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-property-function-functioncode.html#sam-function-functioncode-key) or [Version](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-property-function-functioncode.html#sam-function-functioncode-key) in your CloudFormation template to deploy the new code.

**Update**

`s3://mybucket/319bd03cb3cc8d50ceb80e52bf51c53c` is only your function code, not the template. To update your function using `s3://mybucket/319bd03cb3cc8d50ceb80e52bf51c53c` you have to use AWS Lambda console's `Amazon S3 location`:

[image]

Comment: When you make changes to your script file locally and package it the package command make a new zip file and packaged CF reference the new zip. The new zip file gets a new name (a total random one i think). So as I stated I check so the CodeUri pointed to the new file/new key.

Comment: @ErikAsplund It must be new Key in S3, not the local name of your zip file.

Comment: Well the package command uploads the zip file to s3 under the new zip file name and that name is what is referenced in the new packaged CF file. When you make changes to your code locally the packaged command push a new file to s3 and reference that new file.

Comment: @ErikAsplund I would suggest updating question with your template and maybe screenshots and other code (AWS CLI) that you use. In other words, how can anyone copy-and-paste your code to reproduce the issue?

Comment: I edit the question as suggested. But I don't see the need of sharing the code as it code just be a simpel hello world code you use instead.

Comment: @ErikAsplund "I go to code, the same old code nothing has changed" - are you sure that you look at correct version/alias of your function? Maybe you are checking previous version, not the new one?

Comment: It's only one version of if and it is last modified some days ago (The creation day). So the changes doesn't exist.

Comment: @ErikAsplund I updated the answer because your update procedure in Console is very strange.

Comment: I got this solved.
It was not an issue related to AWS.
After restarting VisualStudioCode I got the deployment to work. So it had to do with some local caching or something.
Really weird never experienced anything like that before.

Comment: @ErikAsplund Glad it worked out. If my answer and comments were helpful, acceptance of the answer would be appreciated.

Comment: It would be wrong to mark it as correct answer due what i did was right from the start. But I thank you for your helping spirit.

Comment: @ErikAsplund Fair enough, but your question does not even mentioned VisualStudioCode. How exactly would anyone be able to determine that you use VisualStudioCode and this was the issue if you can't provide such information in the question?

Comment: It didn't, I had no idea it could be related to it. But thanks again!